# How to get onClick function to work in ipad, jquery-mobile?

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, onclick

I have faced the problem, i'm using jquery-mobile and onClick function in  tags.

```
<a id="stopper" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="stop(); return false;" data-rel="back">back</a>
```

Here is the code, i'm using.

Thing i want to get working is video player. without this, the video keep going even if i change the page.

I have tried many scripts and tricks to get it work, and searched almost all of the forums in here. But still i'm fighting with this.

It works just like i want in pc and android tablet (samsung galaxy tab2) but not in ipad.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$('a#stopper').on('click', function () { your code });`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that doesn't work :( where should i put the code, before or after the video code? Or do U see mistake on my code: <script>

$('a#stoppari').on('click', function () { stop(); });

</script>

Comment: it doesnt matter where you place it. `#stopper` not `#stopperi`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VAUwT/

Comment: Okey, sorry i forgot to change that back, i use finnish id names... i just tried to make it more like english... Thank U very much, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those do not work on the iPad, insert the `rel = "external"` and `href = "edellinensivu.asp"` That works, at least I.

Answer (score 2):

instead of hard coding the `onclick="stop();` as this. You should bind the click event

Something like this

```
$("#stopper").on("click", function(){
  // your code to stop
});
```

Comment: Hi. Can i just put " stop(); " to code, or does it need something more? Because i have tried it already and it doesn't work. I'm sure that i have some mistakes on my code, but i can't find them. That works fine in chrome, but it doesn't work in Ipad :( Thank you